# can't creat local Data base in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a pharmacy software using C# , and i need to create a local data base for staff IDs and pass to use it in login process, but didn't find this option in VS 2015 [when i tried to create it can't find LDbase option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYnPI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more info such database type, local or remote, why.

Maybe what you need is install SQL Server Express, maybe you can use Managment Studio for creating db. But you should share more info.

Thanks.